# Does Windows Store apps or HTML5 Drag and Drop support touch device?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm new to html5 and windows store app. I created a project which I want my image to be able to drag. First for mouse drag it's work just fine but then i tested it in touch device it's not working. Here is the image:

This one is tested on non-touch device and it work:

[image: This one is work with mouse cursor]

This one is tested on touch device and it doesn't work:

[image: Doesn't Work]

here is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Drag and Drop</title>
    </head>

<body>

<div id="content">
    <div id="Store" style="border: solid 1px white;"></div>

    <div id="right" style="border: solid 1px white;">
        <img id="img1" src="/image/bugimgS1.png" />
    </div>

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my script:

```
(function () {
    WinJS.UI.Pages.define('DragandDrop.html',
        {
            ready: function ()
            {
                define();
            }
        });
    function get(ID) { return document.getElementById(ID); }
    function create(tag) { return document.createElement(tag); }
    function define()
    {
        var r = get('Store');
        var img1 = get('img1');
        img1.addEventListener('dragstart', _dragStart, false);
        r.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
        r.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
        r.addEventListener('drop', _dropped, false);


        function _dragStart(e) {
            e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', e.target.id);
        }

        function _dropped(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
            r.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }


    }

})();
```

Please I really need help to make this program work both on touch and non-touch devices. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know why your code isn't working. The theory goes that unless you specifically differentiate between mouse and touch, then touch events should be responded to by all of the basic mouse events (i.e. onclick). Are your events firing at all when you use touch?

Comment: Thanks for your advise :). I put debugger; in my code then when I try to touch and drag the image I noticed that the event didn't fire :). Maybe I need to add another event like you said (i.e. onclick) to make my project work :). Thanks I watched the course 'Developing Windows 8 Apps with HTML5 Jump Start' and i got many knowledge from you and Mr.Michael :). Sorry about my english :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use an [MSGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968035.aspx) object to be able to support drag and drop via touch events. Other events such as `onclick` work seamlessly regardless of mouse pointer, touch, or digitized stylus. The drag events don't currently fire with touch. I've tested this in Chrome and IE.

There's a great demo here: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/BrowserSurface/

Comment: Do you mean this project? https://github.com/molant/MSGestures or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968035.aspx (your link is broken)

Comment: Looks like I missed part of it when I pasted it in. My answer is updated the answer with the correct link. I was linking the MSDN article. I hadn't seen the GitHub project yet, but it looks interesting. I'll check it out!